# How to get an index of XML? (only XPath)

Tags: xml, xpath

First I don't speak english very well.. 
please understand.. sorry

I am currently extracting data using only xpath!

for example..

```
<ROOT>
 <fruit>
   <apple>a</apple>
   <banana>b</banana>
 </fruit>
 <fruit>
  <apple>c</apple>
  <banana>d</banana>
</ROOT>
```

There is this form of XML.
I want to extract the data in the form below.

### seq col1 col2

1  a  b
2  c  d

I know "//fruit[0]/apple" (a)

But My data comes in **dynamically**.
The example above now shows a count of two for fruit.
**However, it is not known what the count(total count) will be for the REAL data..**

How get index?
//fruit[i]/apple
//fruit[i]/banana
How get i(index) ????

Please help me.. please.. please..

Thank you for reading my article!!

Answer (score 0):

Using this xpath you can get the data in your requested format.

for $i in (//root/fruit/position()) return ($i,//fruit[$i])

If you want only index use this,

for $i in (//root/fruit/position()) return $i

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it can be done with XSLT:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/*/fruit">
        <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/fruit/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To use the style sheet:

```
xsltproc fruit.xsl fruit.xml
1 a b
2 c d
```